# Difference between include and block in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

What is the the difference between blocks and using include when you are creating Jade templates? When do you use one over the other?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A block is a placeholder. Its content comes from another jade file.
An include is a placeholder, too. Its content also comes from another jade file.

So far, both are equal.

But:

include embeds a complete file. The including file defines which file is being included. Hence include is fine for outsourcing parts such as a footer or a header, which are always loaded the same way.

A block just defines a placeholder in the top file. Which content is included is not defined by this file, but by a sub-file. So, control over what is included is being reversed.

With an include, A says: Import B.
With a block, B says: Here is content for a placeholder, and please use file A and its placeholders to fill in my content.

include means top-down, blocks mean bottom-up.

Additionally, one file may include several blocks.

When to use what:

- It's common to define the overall layout of a site in a master page with blocks.
- The single pages contain the content for each individual file, reference the master file and fill its blocks.
- Subviews in either the master or the page are being set up using includes.

Does that help?

Comment: For details see "Template inheritance" and "Includes" https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade-language.md#template-inheritance

Comment: So, in order to use blocks you must extend a file with blocks in it?