# When to use block or include in pug?

Tags: pug, view-templates

I have an issue understanding when to use `extends` with `block` rather than `include` in pug templates. Are these two ways of building partials mostly interchangeable or is there a reason why you would use one way rather than the other?

Comment: Check if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170537/difference-between-include-and-block-in-jade#answer-14174164

Comment: It does! Thanks! Didn't find that question when searching.